# Context sensitive grammar for this language

Tags: grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

Language
X = { 0^m such that m = 2n+1 where n >= 0}

Can someone help me find the context sensitive grammar for X? Ive been trying for ages but im still not close.

What i have right now:

S -> B0C|00

B0 -> DD0|00

BD -> DD

0C -> 0EE|00

EC -> EE

D -> B

E -> C

But this doesn't work. I can't figure out how to double the number of zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a simple grammar (even context-free in this case, though I can also make one that isn't), such as:

```
S -> 0 | 00S
```